# Unity(C#) — Почему не работают корутины?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Недавно начал изучать корутины. Не совсем понимаю, как они работают. Я писал скрипт босса для игры, и использовал корутины(впервые). Мне нужно было, чтобы, при переходе на вторую стадию, босс двигался по схемы с корутинов, но при переходе на вторую стадию, он продолжает движение так же, как на первой. Вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Boss2 : Monster
{
[SerializeField]
private float speed = 2.0F; //Скорость передвижения босса
[SerializeField]
public float PosMax1; //Максимальная точка, до которой может дойти босс
[SerializeField]
public float PosMin1; //Минимальная точка, до которой может дойти босс
[SerializeField]
public float PosMax2; //Вторая максимальная точка, до которой может дойти босс
[SerializeField]
public float PosMin2; //Вторая минимальная точка, до которой может дойти босс
[SerializeField]
int HitPoints = 7; //Хп босса (здоровье)
[SerializeField]
int Stadium = 1; //Стадия босса

Vector3 direction;

private SpriteRenderer sprite;

private Bullet bullet;

IEnumerator Waiting() //Создаём корутину, которую потом будем использовать других, для создания задержки в 5 секунд
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5); //Задержка в 5 секунд для будующих корутин
}

IEnumerator Start1() //Создаём корутину, с помощью которой, потом мы будем опускать босса на 10 вниз
{
    transform.position+=Vector3.down*10*Mathf.Sin(Time.deltaTime); //Опускаем босса на 10 вниз
    Debug.Log ("Complite"); //Проверяем, выполнилась ли корутина
}

IEnumerator Start2() //Создаём корутину, с помощью которой, потом мы будем двигать босса вправо, влево в течении 5 секунд
{
    yield return StartCoroutine(Waiting());
    if (transform.position.x >= PosMax2) 
    {
        direction *= -1.0F;
    } 
    else if (transform.position.x <= PosMin2) 
    {
        direction = transform.right;
    }
    Debug.Log ("Complite"); //Проверяем, выполнилась ли корутина
}

IEnumerator Start3() //Создаём корутину, с помощью которой, потом мы будем поднимать босса на 10 вверх
{
    yield return StartCoroutine(Waiting());
    transform.position+=Vector3.up*10*Mathf.Sin(Time.deltaTime);
    Debug.Log ("Complite"); //Проверяем, выполнилась ли корутина
}

IEnumerator Start4() //Создаём корутину, с помощью которой, потом мы будем двигать босса вправо, влево в течении 5 секунд
{
    yield return StartCoroutine(Waiting());
    if (transform.position.x >= PosMax1) 
    {
        direction *= -1.0F;
    } 
    else if (transform.position.x <= PosMin1) 
    {
        direction = transform.right;
    }
    Debug.Log ("Complite"); //Проверяем, выполнилась ли корутина
}

void Start5() //Создадим метод, благодаря которому, потом продолжим движение босса, как на первой стадии без всяких задержек в 5 секунд
{
    if (transform.position.x >= PosMax1) 
    {
        direction *= -1.0F;
    } 
    else if (transform.position.x <= PosMin1) 
    {
        direction = transform.right;
    }
}

protected override void Awake()
{
    sprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer> ();
    bullet = Resources.Load<Bullet>("Bullet");
}

protected override void Start()
{
    direction = transform.right; //Изначальное направление босса - право
    Stadium = 1; //Изначальная стадия босса - 1
}

void Update ()
{
    Move ();
}

public void Damaged() //Создание логики уменьшения хп босса + логики перехода на вторую стадию
{
    HitPoints--; //Отнимаем здоровье
    if (Stadium == 1 && HitPoints == 0) //Если босс находится на первой стадии, и его хп стало 0, переходим на вторую стадию и регенерируем здоровье
    {
        Stadium = 2;
        HitPoints = 10;
    } 
    else if (Stadium == 2 && HitPoints == 0) //Если босс находится на второй стадии, и его хп стало 0, уничтожаем босса
    {
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
}

protected virtual void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    Bullet bullet = collider.GetComponent<Bullet> ();

    if (bullet) //Если в босса попали пулей - отнимаем ему хп
    {
        Damaged ();
    }

    Character character = collider.GetComponent<Character> ();

    if (character) //Если босс ударил игрока - отнимаем здоровье игроку
    {
        character.ReceiveDamage ();
    }
}


private void Move() //Логика движения босса
{
    if (Stadium == 1)  //Если босс находится на первой стадии - двигаем его вправо, влево, пока он не перейдет на вторую стадию или не убьет игрока
    {
        if (transform.position.x >= PosMax1) 
        {
            direction *= -1.0F;
        } 
        else if (transform.position.x <= PosMin1) 
        {
            direction = transform.right;
        }
    } 
    else if (Stadium == 2) //Если босс перешел на вторую стадию - двигаем бесконечно босса по нужному нам скрипту (движение вправо, влево => спуск вниз => движение вправо, влево => поднятие наверх)
    {
        Start5 (); //Продолжаем движение босса как на первой стадии, без задержки
        while (true) //Дабы движение босса по заданому скрипту повторялось, обернем это дело в бесконечный цикл
        {
        StartCoroutine(Start1()); //Стартуем первый корутин - ждём 5 секунд, затем опускаем босса на 10 вниз
            StartCoroutine(Start2()); //Стартуем второй корутин - двигаем босса от точки к точке в течении 5 секунд(в начале можно засечь 5 секунд)
        StartCoroutine(Start3()); //Стартуем третий корутин - поднимаем босса наверх на 10
        StartCoroutine(Start4()); //Стартуем четвертый корутин - двигаем босса от точки к точке в течении 5 секунд 
        } 
        //С этого должно получиться бесконечное передвижение босса по заданому нами направлнии(скрипту)
    }
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, transform.position + direction, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    sprite.flipX = direction.x > 0.0F;
}
```

}

Буду рад вашей помощи. 
P.S. Я новичок, и это мой первый проект

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы же заметили, что Start5 у вас обычный метод, а не корутина, верно?

Трудно, конечно, понять магию, которая у вас там происходит, поэтому код не трогаю, а помогу по сути синтаксиса: все корутины должны запускаться через StartCoroutine(), а у вас простой вызов метода - поэтому и не работает.

А движение, как в первой стадии у вас потому, что первая стадия и метод Start5 содержат один и тот же код. Т.к. метод Start5 не является корутиной, то он единственный из ваших вызовов во второй стадии срабатывает и, как следствие, разницы в движении вы не замечаете.

Вот вам [статья на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/216185/), где более менее подробно про корутины расписано. Возможно, немного поможет в осознании :)

Comment: Спасибо вам) Статью уже читал)

Comment: Можете посоветовать с альтернативной реализацией цикла? Когда босс переходит на вторую стадию, игра зависает, я так понимаю, из-за for( ; ; )

Comment: @Артём, да, совершенно верно - for(;;) - это бесконечный цикл. Т.е. в методе Update(), который вызывается каждый кадр вы вызываете бесконечный цикл (который вызывается, конечно же один раз и вешает игру). Какое поведение вы хотели запрограммировать? Ну, кратко, что вы хотели сделать с помощью коррутин?

Comment: При переходе на эту стадию, босс должен ходить туда сюда по скрипту бесконечно. Я уже наладил логику его походок, могу скинуть, если нужно.

Comment: @Артём, уже работает, как задумывали?

Comment: Я вот с заменой циклу for ( ; ; ) не разобрался, а так надеюсь заработает

Comment: @Артём, ну, я просто не совсем понимаю, что вы хотели получить от этого цикла. Корутины могут передавать управление внутри себя другим корутинам, через yield return StartCoroutine(), в таком случае корутина, которая это вызвала останавливается до тех пор, пока вызванная не завершится. Но если подряд просто вызвать несколько корутин из обычного метода - они начнут выполняться одновременно. Чего именно вы хотели добиться используя бесконечный цикл?

Comment: Изменил код. Проверьте пожалуйста. Вкратце: Есть 5 корутин. Одна создаётся для создания задержки в будущих корутинах. При переходе на вторую стадию, используется 4 корутины, которые задают направление боссу, чтобы заставить его ходить по скрипту бесконечно, я хотел обернуть 4 корутины в цикл